# Finding combinations from a list of objects and sorting them according to property value

Tags: c#

I have a List of type CardSlot, each of these CardSlot objects will contain different cards , say , Card1, Card2, Card3 (The number may differ).

Each CardSlot object has maximum quantity of Card1, Card2 and Card3 pre-set. Now, user inputs the amount of Cards required and should get a combination of CardSlot that fulfill the criteria.

For Eg:

```
 List<CardSlot> listCardSlot = new List<CardSlot>();
 CardSlot cardSlot1 = new CardSlot();
 cardSlot1.Name = "cardSlot1";
 cardSlot1.Price = 900;
 cardSlot1.Card1 = 2;
 cardSlot1.Card2 = 3;
 cardSlot1.Card3 = 4;
 listCardSlot.Add(cardSlot1);

 CardSlot cardSlot2 = new CardSlot();
 cardSlot2.Name = "cardSlot2";
 cardSlot2.Price = 850;
 cardSlot2.Card1 = 3;
 cardSlot2.Card2 = 2;
 cardSlot2.Card3 = 4;
 listCardSlot.Add(cardSlot2);

 CardSlot cardSlot3 = new CardSlot();
 cardSlot3.Name = "cardSlot3";
 cardSlot3.Price = 950;
 cardSlot3.Card1 = 4;
 cardSlot3.Card2 = 3;
 cardSlot3.Card3 = 2;
 listCardSlot.Add(cardSlot3);
```

Now, if user inputs Card1 = 4, Card2 = 5 and Card3 = 4, the end result should be the combination of CardSlot objects with the least possible price.

Can someone please give me a nudge in the right direction?Kindly tell me if something is unclear and I'll try and improve it.

**Edit**

I have tried finding all the possible combinations that can be in the list using following function:

```
public static List<List<T>> ItemCombinations<T>(List<T> inputList, int minimumItems = 1)
    {
        int nonEmptyCombinations = (int)Math.Pow(2, inputList.Count) - 1;
        List<List<T>> listOfCombinations = new List<List<T>>(nonEmptyCombinations + 1);

        if (minimumItems == 0)  
            listOfCombinations.Add(new List<T>());

        for (int i = 1; i <= nonEmptyCombinations; i++)
        {
            List<T> thisCombination = new List<T>(inputList.Count);
            for (int j = 0; j < inputList.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((i >> j) % 2 != 0)
                    thisCombination.Add(inputList[j]);
            }

            if (thisCombination.Count >= minimumItems)
                listOfCombinations.Add(thisCombination);
        }

        return listOfCombinations;
    }
```

This successfully returns all the possible combinations. However, it still does not take care of the situations where repeated occurance of the same card slot may be the correct choice. For e.g in the above mentioned scenario the correct choice would be 1 X CardSlot1 + 1 X CardSlot2

**Edit 2**

I reached an intermediate solution and have posted it as an answer, It still does not give me required answer in case of mix and match combinations. Could anyone take a look and suggest something towards that end ?

Comment: You probably need to add way more info - I maybe having a stupid day but theres nothing indicating how you varied the prices.. however id imagine its a simple maths calculation as to which is the cheapest order.

Comment: @vc 74 The user enters the requirement as in "These are the types and number of cards I want, the *combination* of CardSlot you provide should be the cheapest and cover the requirement (Can be more than required, not less)" , So , the result should be 2 CardSlot2 as that combination is cheapest

Comment: @BugFinder, the prices I used are just random values

Comment: so you want to search the list and find the elements that come close to the requirement and then take the cheapest of them?

Comment: wow, that's a whole algorithm that you are asking for. What have you done so far? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, the combination should result in either the same number of elements as requirement or more though, not less.

Comment: You are going to try following 1) One cardSlot1 2) One cardSlot2 3) One cardSlot3 4) One cardSlot1 & One cardSlot2 5) One cardSlot1 & One cardSlot3 6) One cardSlot2 & One cardSlot3 7) Two cardSlot1  8) Two cardSlot2 9) Two cardSlot3.  then combinations of three card slots.

Comment: @MongZhu I tried and found all possible combinations of CardSlots that can occur in the list, however there's that. I need some direction as to how to progress after that

Comment: please post the code, and we can help from there

Comment: I have edited the question, and added the part that finds all the combinations

Comment: @RMad9248 Hello, if you are stuck at your algorithm, do check my solution at once. I won't say it is by any chance perfect, but seems to be working in my eyes. Maybe I've gone blind doing it :D

Answer (score 0):

So i have made a solution for this, must say it's a headburn for me, but have tried something.

**CardSlot** Class I made:

```
public class CardSlot
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public double Price { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Card1 { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Card2 { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Card3 { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

and then the rest follows as:

```
  //your code
  //as above
  //in the question
  listCardSlot.Add(cardSlot3); //your code

  ValueChecker(1);

  double lowestamount = mycards.Any() ? mycards.Min(item => item.Price) : 0;

  MessageBox.Show("You need " + multiplier.ToString() + " " + 
                   ReturnLowestCardSlot(lowestamount).Name);
}

int a = 4, b = 5, c = 4; //User entered values

int multiplier = 0;

List<CardSlot> mycards = new List<CardSlot>();
CardSlot ReturnLowestCardSlot(double lowestPrice)
{
    CardSlot cardslot = null;
    foreach (var item in mycards)
    {
        if (item.Price == lowestPrice)
        {
            cardslot = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cardslot;
}

void ValueChecker(int increment)
{
    multiplier += increment;
    foreach (CardSlot item in listCardSlot)
    {
        if (((multiplier * item.Card1) >= a) &&
            ((multiplier * item.Card2) >= b) && 
            ((multiplier * item.Card3) >= c))
        {
            if (!(mycards.Contains(item)))
                mycards.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (mycards.Count == 0)
       ValueChecker(1);
  }
```

The Output I'm getting is:

> You need 2 cardSlot1

Hope you could tweak this one somehow to fit your need

**EDIT** 
I see that you want output as `2 cardslot2` which has :

```
cardSlot2.Card1 = 3;
cardSlot2.Card2 = 2;
cardSlot2.Card3 = 4;
```

2 x CardSlot2 will give:

```
cardSlot2.Card1 = 6;
cardSlot2.Card2 = 4;
cardSlot2.Card3 = 8;
```

But the user's requirement is `usercard1 = 4` , `usercard1 = 5` & `usercard1 = 4`.
Here `Card2 = 4` is still lesser than `usercard2 = 5`
I don't see how it fulfils the requirement.

**EDIT 2**

your comment is right, I didn't though of that. now this will give you the result:

```
  //codes same
  //as your question
  ValueChecker(1);

  double lowestamount = mycards.Any() ? mycards.Min(item => item.Price) : 0;

  CardSlot leastcard = ReturnLowestCardSlot(lowestamount, mycards);

  double lowestamount2 = listCardSlot.Any() ? listCardSlot.Min(item => item.Price) : 0;

  CardSlot lowestcard = ReturnLowestCardSlot(lowestamount2, listCardSlot);

  if ((leastcard.Price + lowestcard.Price) > (multiplier * leastcard.Price))
       MessageBox.Show("You need " + multiplier.ToString() + " " + leastcard.Name);

  else
       MessageBox.Show("You need 1 " + leastcard.Name + " and 1 " + lowestcard.Name);
}
```

And modified `ReturnLowestCardSlot`

```
CardSlot ReturnLowestCardSlot(double lowestPrice, List<CardSlot> list)
{
    CardSlot cardslot = null;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Price == lowestPrice)
        {
            cardslot = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cardslot;
}
```

Output:

> You need 1 cardSlot1 and 1 cardSlot2

Comment: My bad about the 2 X CardSlot2, will edit in the question. Still 1 XCardSlot1 + 1X CardSlot2 , is the correct answer as per requirements. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @RMad9248 I've updated my answer, check **Edit 2**. I still think it needs some more modification

Comment: It works for the given scenario. However, breaks for larger samples and always returns "You need 1 CardSlot2 + 1CardSlot2". With a little modification, I am sure this will work

Comment: Yes Im still figuring out how to bring the exact count. Damn its getting harder than I actually anticipated. In the meanwhile if you figured it out, feel free to modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nobody (this sure sounds rude :D ), here is an intermediate (albeit not very optimal) solution I reached. This gives a combination (List of CardSlots) that will be the cheapest.

It does not however provide an answer when the answer should be a heterogenous solution (say 5 X CardSlot1, 3 X CardSlot2, 1 X CardSlot3). Any help towards this will be much appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Some Code
        // Get user input card1, card2, card3
        List<List<CardSlot>> validCombination = GetAllCombinations(card1, card2, card3, listCardSlot);

        List<CardSlot> CheapestCombo = GetLeastPricedCombination(validCombination);
        //Here I get the cheapest homogenous combination 
    }

    private static List<List<CardSlot>> GetAllCombinations(int card1, int card2, int card3, List<CardSlot> listCardSlot)
    {

        var listOfCombinations = ItemCombinations(listCardSlot, 1);

        List<List<CardSlot>> validCombination = new List<List<CardSlot>>();
        int multiplier;

        foreach (List<CardSlot> combination in listOfCombinations)
        {
            multiplier = 1;
            if (CheckMaterialSum(combination, card1, card2, card3, ref multiplier))
            {
                validCombination.Add(combination);
            }
            else
            {
                GetMultiplierCombination(combination, card1, card2, card3, ref validCombination, ref multiplier);
            }
        }

        return validCombination;
    }

    private static bool CheckMaterialSum(List<CardSlot> combination, int card1, int card2, int card3, ref int multiplier)
    {
        int sumcard1 = multiplier * (combination.Sum(comb => comb.Card1));
        int sumcard2 = multiplier * (combination.Sum(comb => comb.Card2));
        int sumcard3 = multiplier * (combination.Sum(comb => comb.Card3));

        if (sumcard1 >= card1 && sumcard2 >= card2 && sumcard3 >= card3)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void GetMultiplierCombination(List<CardSlot> combination, int card1, int card2, int card3, ref List<List<CardSlot>> validCombination, ref int multiplier)
    {
        while (!CheckMaterialSum(combination, card1, card2, card3, ref multiplier))
        {
            multiplier += 1;
        }
        List<CardSlot> interMediateCombo = new List<CardSlot>();
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
        {
            interMediateCombo.AddRange(combination);
        }
        validCombination.Add(interMediateCombo);
    }


    private static List<CardSlot> GetLeastPricedCombination(List<List<CardSlot>> validCombination)
    {
        List<CardSlot> cheapestCombo = new List<CardSlot>();
        int leastPrice = int.MaxValue;
        int priceTotal;

        //Find better way for finding least priced combination
        foreach (List<CardSlot> combination in validCombination)
        {
            priceTotal = combination.Sum(combo => combo.Price);

            if (priceTotal < leastPrice)
            {
                leastPrice = priceTotal;
            }
        }

        foreach (List<CardSlot> combination in validCombination)
        {
            priceTotal = combination.Sum(combo => combo.Price);

            if(priceTotal == leastPrice)
            {
                cheapestCombo.AddRange(combination);
                break;
            }
        }

        return cheapestCombo;
    }
```